# error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct student’ root->next->student_number = 17;

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
//------libraries
#include <stdio.h>  //library for basic input/output
#include <stdlib.h> //library for memory allocations

//------structures
typedef struct{
    unsigned short int student_number;
    struct student *next;
}student;

int main( void){
    student *root;
    root = (student *)malloc(sizeof(student));

    root->student_number = 5;   //works
    printf("root student_number = %d\n", root->student_number);

    root->next = (student *)malloc(sizeof(student));
    root->next->student_number = 17;           //here is the problem
    printf("root->next = %d\n", root->next->student_number);
}
```

I created a structure **student**. Defined a root that points to the first element of a linked list. It is possible to reach the fist linked list element(print root->student_number). Everything is nice until here:
allocated memory for the second element of the linked list(root->next), but I cant assign a value to a variable student_number, print respectively.
How it is possible to reach second and next elements of linked list?
will be so glad for help :)

Answer (score 3):

You `typedef`ed an anonymous struct.  `struct student` does not exist.  Try this:

```
typedef struct student{
    unsigned short int student_number;
    struct student *next;
}student;
```